# Fonts doesn't change in the android emulator but works fine in the Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview, android-fonts

So everytime I run the app in the emulator the font's does not work. I have the

```
android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
```

for the specific TextView but it does not appear like that when I run the app.

[image]

This is how its suppose to look and it looks like that in the preview . But when I run the app it looks like below .

[image]

Comment: What android version does the device you running the app on has?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the emulator and it will update your font family

Answer (score 0):

check how you change the font , and try to check if it's working with the emulator sdk version